# Narration which says Jesus was 120 years old

Tags: hadith

Can someone verify this hadith:

> **وَأَخْبَرَنِي أَنَّهُ أَخْبَرَهُ أَنَّهُ لَمْ يَكُنْ نَبِيٌّ إِلا عَاشَ نِصْفَ عُمَرَ الَّذِي كَانَ قَبْلَهُ، وَأَنَّهُ أَخْبَرَنِي أَنَّ عِيسَى ابْنَ مَرْيَمَ عَاشَ عِشْرِينَ وَمِئةَ سَنَةٍ وَلا أُرَانِي ذَاهِبًا عَلَى رَأْسِ السِّتِّينَ**
>
> And I have been told that there is no Prophet after other Prophet but
> he lives a life half then the one who lived earlier. And I have been
> told that Jesus, the son of Mary lived for a hundred and twenty years
> and I do not see myself but approaching sixties
>
> Mu'jam Tabarani 18464

Comment: @Medi1Saif I provided a suitable/rough translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

وَأَخْبَرَنِي أَنَّهُ أَخْبَرَهُ أَنَّهُ لَمْ يَكُنْ نَبِيٌّ إِلا عَاشَ نِصْفَ عُمَرَ الَّذِي كَانَ قَبْلَهُ، وَأَنَّهُ أَخْبَرَنِي أَنَّ عِيسَى ابْنَ مَرْيَمَ عَاشَ عِشْرِينَ وَمِئةَ سَنَةٍ وَلا أُرَانِي ذَاهِبًا عَلَى رَأْسِ السِّتِّينَ

“And I have been told that there is no Prophet after other Prophet but he lives a life half then the one who lived earlier. And I have been told that Jesus, the son of Mary lived for a hundred and twenty years and I do not see myself but approaching sixties”
(Mu’jam Tabarani Kabeer Hadith 18464, Tarikh Damishq 47/481-482 quoted in Kanz Al-Ummal 11/479 H.32262 & 13/676 H.37732)

Narration

Yahya bin Ayyub Al-‘Allaaf Al-Mishriy -- Ibnu Abi Maryam -- Nafi’ bin Yaziid -- Ibnu Gaziyyah('Umarah) -- Muhammad bin Abdillah bin ‘Amr bin Utsman -- Fathimah binti Al-Hasan -- Aisha said that: "Verily, the Prophet shallallahu 'alayhi wa sallam said on the day of his illness before his death to Fatima radhiyallahu 'anha: .."

Hafiz Haithmi has called it Daeef (i.e. unauthentic). After quoting this narration he writes:

رواه الطبراني باسناد ضعيف ، وروى البزار بعضه أيضا وفى رجاله ضعف

“Tabarani narrated it with a weak chain and Bazzar also narrated some part of it and in its chain (also) is weakness.”
(Majma’ Al-Zawai’d Wa Manba Al-Fawai’d 4/67, Chapter on the illness and death of the Prophet)

Al-Hafidz Ibn Hajar said: The narrators of this hadith is tsiqah until Muhammad bin Abdillah bin 'Amr bin Uthman bin 'Affan who is more known as Ad-Diibaaj. [Al-Arba'in Al-Mutabayinah As-Simaa']

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 1):

The hadith is not reliable by its content, considering that Muhammad (p.b.u.h) lived about 600 years after Jesus (p.b.u.h). His apparent death was before he turned 40. It is expected that he returns one day.  It has been said that he would come back on Earth and die. This is deduced from a hadith saying that he would be buried at the side of Muhammad (p.b.u.h). According to the Gospel he will see his apostles on the last day.
Whatever we accept, nobody ever claimed that he had come back before Muhammad (p.b.u.h) what would have been the case if he died at the age of 120 years.

Comment: I want an analysis of the chain not a guess.

Comment: I don't have it. But even a good chain does not make a hadith 100%. If it stands in opposition to all other information, the chain would not make it reliable.